# Select column that begins with underscore in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a KDB table stored in a server, where some columns begins with underscore (ex: _columnName). When trying to select such columns I get the following error (An error occurred during execution of the query. The server sent the response : _ ).

What would be the best way to get around this error ?

Thanks

Comment: `_` are not recommended for column names. You can get away with them when they are in the middle but at the start means you can't freely query with qSQL. Maurice's answer with functional form is the only way.

Comment: This is due to the confusion with the drop operator `_`

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a functional select like the following:

```
q)tbl:flip(`$"_a";`$"_b";`c)!(til 3;til 3;til 3)
q)parse"select a from tbl"
?
`tbl
()
0b
(,`a)!,`a
q)?[`tbl;();0b;(enlist`$"_a")!enlist`$"_a"]
_a
--
0
1
2
```

Comment: Functional select was the solution. Thanks Maurice !

Answer (score 1):

If you really want/need to use qSQL, you can instead query a version of the table with renamed columns, using `xcol`:

```
q)tbl:flip(`$"_a";`$"_b";`c)!3 3#til 3
q)select ua from xcol[(`$("_a";"_b"))!`ua`ub;tbl]
ua
--
0
1
2
```

Then in all of your queries to the server, you would replace the table name with `` xcol[(`$("_a";"_b"))!`ua`ub;tbl] ``

Note: if you're querying the server using the common `h"<query>"` style, you'll need to escape the speech marks, i.e. `` xcol[(`$(\"_a\";\"_b\"))!`ua`ub;tbl] ``

Answer (score 0):

I would of thought .Q.id(sanitize) might of achieved Kyle's solution but looks like it doesn't. Could expand on Kyles to do the `xcol` programmatically.

```
sanitize:{(`$ .[string cols t;(::;0);{$["_" ~ x;"u";x]}]) xcol t}

sanitize[t]
ua ub c
-------
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
```